# Going to the next page using Python 3 and BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse data from a tables on multiple pages of a web site using Python 3 and BeautifulSoup 4. Everything is working well except some of the pages have tables that exceed the length of the page. The page shows only 20 entries and to get the additional entries one would need to click the Next at the bottom of the table to move to the next page where the table data continues.
I have tries using

```
nextPage = re.compile(b'Next</a>')
```

and

```
nextPageUrl = nextPage.findall(webContent)
```

I know this is not BeautifulSoup. I tried this because I don't know how to do this using BeutifulSoup. However, it does not work. Can someone please help me and suggest how I can get the next page url to continue scraping? Thank you for any suggestions you may be able to provide.

Comment: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16992100/edit) with an example of how an html markup for the link looks like e.g., `...<a href="...">Next</a> ...`

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean but the markup you indicated above is exactly it. Thank you for your help. It worked nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent)
a = soup.find('a', href=True, text=re.compile("Next"))
if a:
    link = a["href"]
```